# Why do I have a syntax error on the last line?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, syntax-error

```
//Caleb Howe Homework 5
public class MyStudent {

        public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Output print  
            Individual mine = new Individual();
            System.out.println("The last name of the "+ "student is " + mine.lname + " and the first name is " + mine.fname);
            System.out.println("The email address is " + mine.getemail());
            System.out.println("The UUID is " + mine.getUUID());
            System.out.println("-----------------------------------------");
            Individual Student2= new Individual("Jones", "John", "BITS", "Senior","3.5");
            System.out.println("The name of the Student is "+ Student2.fname+" "+Student2.lname);
            System.out.println("The email of the student is " +Student2.getemail());
            System.out.println("The GPA of the student is "+ Student2.gpa1);
            System.out.println("The major of the student is "+ Student2.qualification);
            System.out.println("The Student is a "+ Student2.year1);
            System.out.println("Press any key to continue . . .");
        }
}
        //class template for student
class Individual{
        //data for students
        String fname = "Caleb";
        String lname = "Howe";
        String qualification;
        String department;
        String year1;
        String gpa1;

        // constructor (bare minimum)
        public Individual(){

        }

        //constructor
        public Individual(String last, String first, String BBA, String year, String gpa){
            lname = last;
            fname = first;
            qualification = BBA;
            year1 = year;
            gpa1=gpa;
        }
        //constructor
        public String getemail(){
            String value = "default";
            int amount;
            value = fname;
            String email = "default";
            email = value.charAt(0)+lname+"@memphis.edu";
            return email;
        }
        //constructor
        public String getUUID(){
            String id = "";
            int number;
            number = (int) ((Math.random()*100)+1.00);
            id = number +fname.substring(0,1) + lname.substring(0, 1);
        }
}
```

When I compile this it gives me a syntax error because of the semicolon.
Cannot figure out why, any help would be appreciated!

Comment: That's not a *Minimal* example.  When you [edit] your post to fix this, you should also include the *exact* error message from compiling the [mcve], which will indicate where "the" semicolon is in the code.

Answer (score 3):

Your `getUUID()` method is defined to return a `String`, yet you never `return` anything. You probably meant to add `return id;`. Also, you have several `//constructor` comments by methods that aren't acting as constructors.

Answer (score 1):

Sort out your indentation, give variables a meaningful name. They will help you out better now and in the future.

getEmail and getUUID are not constructors either, which need to return values. A constructor must be the same name as the class.